# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, https

Encountered an error when sending a post request. A local server with a self-signed certificate is used as the server. An https connection is also used.

To connect I use `GetConnect` which is included in the getX package

This error appears:

```
HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
    CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:393))
```

I tried to allow the use of self-signed certificates with the following code, but it didn't help me:

```dart
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host,
          int port) => true;
  }
}
```

Also in the main function I specified the following line:

```dart
HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution :)

You need to add the following line in your class's constructor that extends the GetConnect

allowAutoSignedCert = true;

Comment: great job, thanks by the way.