# How to fetch data from the backend with flutter GetX

Tags: flutter, request, null, backend, response

Please I am trying to fetch data from the backend with flutter GetXService, I am unable to get the data as it keeps telling me that "Null is not a subtype of String". I don't know where am getting it wrong. I follow some youtube videos but still not able to get the response from the server.I used the url on postman and the data is retrieved correctly

Here is my modal class

```
    class Product {
      int? _totalSize;
      int? _typeId;
      int? _offset;
      late List<ProductsModel> _products;
      List<ProductsModel> get products=>_products;
    
      Product({required totalSize, required typeId, required offset, required products}){
        this._totalSize = totalSize;
        this._typeId = typeId;
        this._offset = offset;
        this._products = products;
      }
    
      Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        _totalSize = json['total_size'];
        _typeId = json['type_id'];
        _offset = json['offset'];
        if (json['products'] != null) {
          _products = <ProductsModel>[];
          json['products'].forEach((v) {
            _products!.add(ProductsModel.fromJson(v));
          });
        }
      }
    }
    
    class ProductsModel {
      int? id;
      String? name;
      String? description;
      int? price;
      int? stars;
      String? img;
      String? location;
      String? createdAt;
      String? updatedAt;
      int? typeId;
    
      ProductsModel(
          {this.id,
            this.name,
            this.description,
            this.price,
            this.stars,
            this.img,
            this.location,
            this.createdAt,
            this.updatedAt,
            this.typeId});
    
      ProductsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        id = json['id'];
        name = json['name'];
        description = json['description'];
        price = json['price'];
        stars = json['stars'];
        img = json['img'];
        location = json['location'];
        createdAt = json['created_at'];
        updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
        typeId = json['type_id'];
      }
    }
```

My apiclient class

```
    import 'package:food_app/utils/app_constants.dart';
    import 'package:get/get.dart';
    
    class ApiClient extends GetConnect implements GetxService{
      late String token;
      final String appBaseUrl;
      late Map<String,String> _mainHeaders;
      ApiClient({required this.appBaseUrl}){
        baseUrl = appBaseUrl;
        timeout=Duration(minutes: 5);
        token = AppConstants.TOKEN;
        _mainHeaders = {
          'Content-type':'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        };
      }
      Future<Response> getData(String uri) async {
        try{
          Response response =await get(uri);
          return response;
        }catch(e){
          print("Error from the api client is "+e.toString());
          return Response(statusCode: 1,statusText: e.toString());
    
        }
      }
    }
```

My repository

```
    class PopularProductRepository extends GetxService{
      final ApiClient apiClient;
      PopularProductRepository({required this.apiClient});
    
      Future<Response> getPopularProductList()async{
        return await apiClient.getData(AppConstants.POPULAR_PRODUCTS_URI);
      }
    }
```

My controller

```
    class PopularProductController extends GetxController{
      final PopularProductRepository popularProductRepository;
    
    
      PopularProductController({required this.popularProductRepository});
    
    
      List<ProductsModel> _popularProductList=[];
      List<ProductsModel> get popularProductList => _popularProductList;
    
      Future<void> getPopularProductList()async {
        Response response = await popularProductRepository.getPopularProductList();
    
        try{
    
    
        if(response.statusCode==200){
          print("Got products from the server");
          _popularProductList=[];
          _popularProductList.addAll(Product.fromJson(response.body).products);
          print(_popularProductList);
          update();
        }
        else{
          print("Error occurred and the error is "+response.body);
        }
        }catch(e){
          print("Error in the controller is "+e.toString());
        }
      }
    }
```

init class

```
    Future <void> init()async {
      //api client
      Get.lazyPut(()=>ApiClient(appBaseUrl: AppConstants.BASE_URL));
    
      //repository
      Get.lazyPut(() => PopularProductRepository(apiClient:Get.find()));
    
      //controller
      Get.lazyPut(() => PopularProductController(popularProductRepository:Get.find()));
    }
```

Appconstants for my url

```
    class AppConstants{
    
      static const String APP_NAME = "FoodApp";
      static const int VERSION = 1;
      static const String BASE_URL = "https://mvs.bslmeiyu.com";
      static const String POPULAR_PRODUCTS_URI = "/api/v1/products/popular";
      static const String RECOMMENDED_PRODUCTS_URI = "/api/v1/products/recommended";
      static const String TOKEN = "FoodToken";
    }
```

Here is the Main page

```
    import 'package:get/get.dart';
    import 'helper/dependency.dart' as dep;
    import 'home/main_page.dart';
    
    Future<void> main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await dep.init();
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Get.find<PopularProductController>().getPopularProductList();
        return GetMaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: const MainPage(),// RecommendedFoodDetails(), //PopularFoodDetails(),//
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        );
      }
    }
```

I got this from the logcat

```
    [GETX] Instance "PopularProductController" has been created
    [GETX] Instance "PopularProductRepository" has been created
    [GETX] Instance "ApiClient" has been created
    [GETX] Instance "ApiClient" has been initialized
    [GETX] Instance "PopularProductRepository" has been initialized
    [GETX] Instance "PopularProductController" has been initialized
    [GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been created
    [GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized
    [+2855 ms] I/flutter (  548): Error from the api client is type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
    [   +1 ms] I/flutter (  548): Error in the controller is type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Comment: have you tried this _popularProductList. addAll(Product.fromJson(response.body));

Answer (score 1):

I copied your exact code and it seems to work although I used `Text("test")` instead of `MainPage()` because I don't have that one and it seems to work fine for me. Output:

```
[GETX] Instance "PopularProductController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "PopularProductRepository" has been created
[GETX] Instance "ApiClient" has been created
[GETX] Instance "ApiClient" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "PopularProductRepository" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "PopularProductController" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized
Got products from the server
[Instance of 'ProductsModel', Instance of 'ProductsModel', Instance of 'ProductsModel', Instance of 'ProductsModel', Instance of 'ProductsModel', Instance of 'ProductsModel']
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work for you,  maybe you can try to upgrade your flutter.

Comment: Am using the latest version of flutter, I still don't know why it's not working for me. I don't know if my internet connection is too low

Answer (score 1):

change the https://.... to http will be ok.
Why? I don't know...ask dbestech please...

find the correct solution :

```
allowAutoSignedCert = true;
```

[CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71200480/certificate-verify-failed-flutter)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).